# Why changing the bg color of a JLabel opens another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent, jlabel

So I'm trying to create a chess game in JAVA (self-learning).
I used JFrame to create a frame, JPanel to add it to the frame and JLabel to define the tiles of the chess board.
I want to change the color of a tile by clicking it and I'm using something like this:
This is the method for mouse click.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    this.x = e.getX();
    this.y = e.getY();
    System.out.println("X: " + this.x + "; Y:" + this.y);
    GUI GUIOBject = new GUI();
    GUIOBject.clickOnTile(this.x, this.y);
}
```

The function called here, `GUIObject.clickOnTile(int x, int y);` is this:

```
public void clickOnTile(int x, int y){
    this.labels[x/60 + y/60*8].setBackground(Color.blue);
}
```

The problem is that doing this I get a new window each time a click somewhere.[image]

So when I click on a tile, it colors the right tile, but by opening a new tile.
Any idea why is this and how can I make changes only in that frame?

This is the entire source code:
Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    GUI graphic_user_interface = new GUI();

}
```

GUI.java:

```
public JFrame frame;
public JPanel panel;
public JLabel[] labels;
public String[] positions = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"};

public GUI(){
    this.createFrame();
    this.createPanel();
    this.createLabels();
    this.addPanel();
    this.addLabels();
    this.setFrameVisible();
}

public void clickOnTile(int x, int y){
    this.labels[x/60 + y/60*8].setBackground(Color.blue);
}


@Override
public void createFrame() {
    this.frame = new JFrame();
    this.frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void createPanel() {
    this.panel = new JPanel();
    this.panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
}

private void createLabels(){
    this.labels = new JLabel[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <8; j++) {
            this.labels[i*8 + j] = new JLabel(this.positions[j] + (i+1));
            this.labels[i*8 + j].setBounds(i*10, i*10, 50, 50);
            this.labels[i*8 + j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(1));
            this.labels[i*8 + j].setOpaque(true);

            if(i%2 == 0){
                if(j%2 == 0){
                    this.labels[i*8 + j].setBackground(Color.black);
                }else{
                    this.labels[i*8 + j].setBackground(Color.white);
                }
            }else{
                if(j%2 == 1){
                    this.labels[i*8 + j].setBackground(Color.black);
                }else{
                    this.labels[i*8 + j].setBackground(Color.white);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}

private void addPanel(){
    this.frame.add(this.panel);
}

private void addLabels(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        this.panel.add(this.labels[i]);
    }
}

private void setFrameVisible(){
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-this.frame.getSize().height/2);
    this.frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new Mouse());
    this.frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Mouse.java:
public static int x;
public static int y;

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    this.x = e.getX();
    this.y = e.getY();
    System.out.println("X: " + this.x + "; Y:" + this.y);
    GUI GUIOBject = new GUI();
    GUIOBject.clickOnTile(this.x, this.y);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
```

IGUI (interface):

```
public void createFrame();
public void createPanel();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

In the Mouse class I've created a new object and then call the function to color the JLabel.
I made the label variable static and just change it in Mouse class and it works just fine.